# Have one PageIndexChanging that control more than one Gridview Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I just want to know if it's possible to have one `PageIndexChanging` that will control more than one *Gridview* as shown by the image attached. The data bind in the *Gridview* come from the same table I decided to divide it into 3 Gridviews for a better display of the data. I want one `PageIndexChanging` that will control the 3 Gridviews.

[image]

C# Code filling the gridviews

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
 {
                con.Open();

                // Sample Result Mutation Results Details

       using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT *
                                                            FROM
                                                                    MutationResults 
                                                            WHERE

                                                             SampleBranchID=@SampleBranchID ", con))
         {

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleBranchID", lblSampleBranchID.Text);
             DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
             SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
             da1.Fill(dt1);
              if (dt1 != null && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                        GridViewMYD88.DataSource = dt1;
                        GridViewMYD88.DataBind();
                        GridViewNOTCH1.DataSource = dt1;
                        GridViewNOTCH1.DataBind();
                        GridViewSF3B1.DataSource = dt1;
                        GridViewSF3B1.DataBind();

                    }
                }
         con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: well, in this event you have the sender parameter, maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a method for all the GridViews by casting the `sender` back to a GridView.

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a gridview
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;

    //set the new page index to the gridviw
    gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    //make sure you rebind the correct data per gridview
    gv.DataSource = LoadDataTableFromDB();

    //rebind the data
    gv.DataBind();
}

public static DataTable LoadDataTableFromDB()
{
    string query = "select * from dtabase";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

You only have to make sure you rebind the correct DataSource per GridView. If you only have one for all three then just rebind the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Add your suggestion below

//make sure you rebind the correct data per gridview
            gv.DataSource = GridViewMYD88.ID;
            gv.DataSource = GridViewNOTCH1.ID;
            gv.DataSource = GridViewSF3B1.ID;

            //rebind the data
            gv.DataBind();

but having the error" The data source does not support server-side data paging."

Comment: The datasource should be the same as when you first bind the grids in Page_load. I only added `getCorrectSourceDataByID` as an example.

Comment: I add this   gv.DataSource = GridViewMYD88(gv.ID);
  gv.DataSource = GridViewNOTCH1(gv.ID);
  gv.DataSource = GridViewSF3B1(gv.ID);
I have the error "Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method"
. Any suggestion how to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Show how you are filling the gridviews with data now (by editing your question)

Comment: I added the C# Code to my post. Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is make sure that the above code you posted also gets called when you do a page change. The easiest way is to create a method containing that code that returns a `DataTable`. See my updated answer

Comment: I added your suggestion.  But the page is just changing on the first Gridview. I added GridView_PageIndexChanging to the 3 Gridviews. Thanks